# CMake setup with crosscompilation, modules and libs

Tags: c++, c, cmake, embedded, stm32

I am trying to write a proper CMake script for building an embedded project(STM32). Our project structure looks like this:

```
App/
....Module1/
....Module2/
Core/
....OwnFramework/
........CoreModule1/
........CoreModule2/
....CubeMXGeneratedCode/
........Core/ (there are more files and dirs, but they are not relevant)
...........Src/main.c (only important info is that main is here)
........Drivers/
....Libs/
........Lib1/ (for example ETL)
```

Right now there is one CMakeLists.txt file in root project dir, but this seems like a bad solution. I've tried adding CMakeLists into App/ and App/Module but then I would get linking errors (while looking at compile_commands I've seen that they were compiled with almost no flags).

./CMakeLists.txt (removed some non-important parts, like set variables that are obvious, so it's little bit shorter)

```
set(APP_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
    ${APP_DIR}/Module1
    ${APP_DIR}/Module2
)

set(CORE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
    ${Core_DIR}/CoreModule1
    ${Core_DIR}/CoreModule2
)

set(FLAGS
    "-Wl,--gc-sections")
set(CPP_FLAGS
    "-fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics")

set(CPU_PARAMETERS
    -mcpu=cortex-m4
    -mthumb
    -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16
    -mfloat-abi=hard)

set(STARTUP_SCRIPT ${CUBEMX_DIR}/startup_stm32fxxxxx.s)
set(MCU_LINKER_SCRIPT ${CUBEMX_DIR}/STM32Fxxxxxxx_FLASH.ld)

set(CUBEMX_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
    ${CUBEMX_DIR}/Core/Inc
    ... and some more Inc dirs
set(PROJECT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
    ${APP_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}
    ${CORE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES})

file(GLOB_RECURSE STM32CUBEMX_SOURCES
    ${CUBEMX_DIR}/Core/*.c
    ${CUBEMX_DIR}/Drivers/*.c
    ${CUBEMX_DIR}/Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/*.c)

file(GLOB_RECURSE PROJECT_SOURCES FOLLOW_SYMLINKS
    ${APP_DIR}/*.cpp
    ${APP_DIR}/*.c
    ${CORE_DIR}/*.cpp
    ${CORE_DIR}/*.c)

add_executable(${EXECUTABLE}
    ${STM32CUBEMX_SOURCES} 
    ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
    ${STARTUP_SCRIPT})

target_compile_definitions(${EXECUTABLE} PRIVATE
    ${MCU_MODEL}
    USE_HAL_DRIVER)

target_include_directories(${EXECUTABLE} PRIVATE
    ${CUBEMX_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES}
    ${PROJECT_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES})

target_compile_options(${EXECUTABLE} PRIVATE
    ${CPU_PARAMETERS}
    ${FLAGS}
    -Wall
    -Wextra
    -Wpedantic
    -Wno-unused-parameter
    $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CXX>:
    ${CPP_FLAGS}
    -Wno-volatile
    -Wold-style-cast
    -Wuseless-cast
    -Wsuggest-override>
    $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:-Og -g3 -ggdb>
    $<$<CONFIG:Release>:-Og -g0>)

target_link_options(${EXECUTABLE} PRIVATE
    -T${MCU_LINKER_SCRIPT}
    ${CPU_PARAMETERS}
    -Wl,-Map=${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}.map
    --specs=nosys.specs
    -Wl,--start-group
    -lc
    -lm
    -lstdc++
    -lsupc++
    -Wl,--end-group
    -Wl,--print-memory-usage)

add_custom_command(TARGET ${EXECUTABLE} POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_SIZE} $<TARGET_FILE:${EXECUTABLE}>)

add_custom_command(TARGET ${EXECUTABLE} POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} -O ihex $<TARGET_FILE:${EXECUTABLE}>
    ${EXECUTABLE}.hex
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} -O binary $<TARGET_FILE:${EXECUTABLE}>
    ${EXECUTABLE}.bin)
```

There is also toolchain file:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

set(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX arm-none-eabi-)
set(FLAGS
    "-fdata-sections -ffunction-sections \
    --specs=nano.specs -Wl,--gc-sections")

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}gcc ${FLAGS})
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER})
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}g++ ${FLAGS})
set(CMAKE_OBJCOPY ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}objcopy)
set(CMAKE_SIZE ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}size)

set(CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX_ASM ".elf")
set(CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX_C ".elf")
set(CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX_CXX ".elf")

set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

I am building everything with this command:

```
cmake -B${workspaceFolder}/build -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=gcc-arm-none-eabi.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

And this setup works, but I have a feeling that this is a vary bad way of doing it. When I tried adding subdirectories in App and each module, I've got linking erros due to problems with compile flags (arm none eabi elf uses VFP register arguments linking error).
I am also not sure how well will it work when I start adding libs like Embedded Template Library.
So my question is, how do I add subdirectories so they compile the same way my root CMakeLists does? I've tried doing this following multiple guides and examples like this one: https://github.com/rgujju/STM32_Base_Project/blob/master/modules/simple_module/CMakeLists.txt.
But when I've put this in my App/Module/CMakeLists.txt

```
set(MODULE_NAME simple_module)

file(GLOB SOURCES ./*.c)

add_library(${MODULE_NAME} STATIC
    ${SOURCES}
    )

target_include_directories(${MODULE_NAME}
    PUBLIC
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
    )
```

And added add_subdirectory(App) to main, my generated commands for modules where without most of my flags and didn't link.
If anyone has experience with dividing CMake project into modules, libs and subdirectories, I would gladly accept any help.

Comment: Your code specifies different kind of flags, so it is not clear which ones are missed when build your library (or executable?). "So my question is, how do I add subdirectories so they compile the same way my root CMakeLists does?" - Your don't specify what is "the same way", but normally a `CMakeLists.txt` could do the same things as root `CMakeLists.txt` does. Please, be specific when describe your problem: show the **exact error message**, **exact generated commands** and so on. Note, that there is no "the best project layout" in CMake. So the most we can is to fix your **specific issues**.

Comment: Yeah, I now realized how bad my og post was. I've just spent so many hours trying to get it right, that i wasn't able to explain that properly. I will update my post soon, so it explains my problem better.